# Javascript eval() not working with passed string

Tags: javascript, eval

My code snippet:

```
function receive(mag)
{
    var text = eval(mag);
    alert(text);
}

receive('["magnolia,", ["Magnolia (Flower)"], [], [], [], [], [], [[3, 19019, "INV_MAG_39 ", 5]]]');
```

When I pass the string in the example (shown above), the `eval(mag)` doesn't work.
But if I do it directly like this:

```
function receive(mag)
{
    var text = eval('["magnolia,", ["Magnolia (Flower)"], [], [], [], [], [], [[3, 19019, "INV_MAG_39 ", 5]]]');
    alert(text);
}
```

It does work.
Does anyone have an idea whats wrong / how can I get it working with passed variable?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What actually happens with the first version? (Do you get any errors in the console?)

Comment: @nnnnnn well rest of the code just won't execute, normal if something is wrong.

Comment: @AlienWebguy you helped me a lot, not.

Comment: No really, stop using `eval()`.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Might want to explain why and/or offer a better solution or idea instead of just being dismissive.

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Because eval will execute _anything_ inside the string, and since it only makes sense to eval external data, it is potentially very dangerous.

Comment: Your code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/HvrzK/

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing the parenthesis:

```
eval('(' + mag + ')')
```

But why not use JSON.parse??

```
var text = JSON.parse(mag);
```

Comment: Why do the parentheses matter when including the string directly works without them? (And even the "broken" code works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/HvrzK/ - tested with Chrome.)

Comment: Well, i've only included like-code because the original is too long to post. But you get my point; what it does in real code is get string with ajax and pass it to a function.

Comment: Because the a json string that starts with a curly brace "{" will make the content of the string interpreted as a statement instead of an object. Your "broken" code isn't valid json as it's not wrapped around {} so the eval works.

Comment: JSON doesn't require `{}` to be valid - JSON supports arrays.

Comment: @nnnnnn: yes, you're right arrays too. Anyway, the correct syntax is eval('(' + mag + ')')

Comment: Frenchie I've tried with your syntax but it unfortunately doesn't work still.

Comment: What's not working? What error are you getting? The syntax is correct so if you're not getting the result you want, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @xtra: Check the web browser's console log. It'll give you the exact cause of error on the exact string passed to the `receive` function. The string from your example does work, so it's likely that the error occured on a different string.